# Searching for Files with specific Regex in filename in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, file, search

Hi all I was wondering how I can go about searching for files in perl.

Right now I have a line with information that I have tokenized with tab as a delimiter stored into an array. (using split) These arrays contain stub text of filenames I want to search for in a directory. For example Engineering_4.txt would just be "Engin" in my array.

If there are two different files... Engineering_4 and Engineering_5, it would search both these files for content and just extract the information I need from one of them (only 1 contains information I want). I would imagine my script will have to search and store all file names that match and then search through each of these files.

My question is how do I go about searching for files in a directory matching a regular expression in Perl? Also is there a way to limit the file types that I want to search for. For example, I just want to only search for ".txt" files.

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess since you already know the directory you could open it and read it while also filtering it :

```
opendir D, 'yourDirectory' or die "Could not open dir: $!\n";
my @filelist = grep(/yourRegex/i, readdir D);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) function of `<glob>` operator.

```
while (<Engin*.txt>) {
 print "$_\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) function returns an array of matching files when provided a wildcard expression.

This means that the files can also be `sort`-ed before processing:

```
use Sort::Key::Natural 'natsort';

foreach my $file ( natsort glob "*.txt" ) {  # Will loop over only txt files

    open my $fh, '<', $file or die $!; # Open file and process
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the File::Find module:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;
my @dirs = @ARGV ? @ARGV : ('.');
my @list;
find( sub{
    push @list, $File::Find::name if -f $_ && $_ =~ m/.+\.txt/ },
    @dirs );
print "$_\n" for @list;
```